# Fortran compiler that would work with Windows Azure?

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, fortran

Does anyone know of a Fortran compiler that can be used inside a Windows Azure project? I am ultimately looking to take a fortran code I have upgraded with MPI and get it to run inside Azure.

I can run the code already on EC2 but integrating a web ui has been klunky as there are a lot of moving parts - IIS, mpi nodes and the like that I would like to filter out.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean how to use Fortran with the Azure SDK, or do you mean how a compiled Fortran project can be run on the Azure platform?

Comment: the latter. I edited the post to give some clarity to what I am looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your FORTRAN code is compliled to a dll library or an executable file you may :

- Use P/Invoke to call the FORTRAN library from a web or worker role
- Spawn a subproccess that runs the FORTRAN executable from a web or worker role

In both cases you need to set the attribute **enableNativeCodeExecution="true"** for the web or worker role in the ServiceDefinition File

A complete example of the above is the [FullTrust Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573374.aspx) in the Windows Azure SDK

Answer (score 1):

For rather simple programs you can use [Fortran Online](http://ideone.com) (free)